# Question about integral with second derivative of Newtonian potential (Weinberg 9.9)

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics, integration, post-newtonian

I have a question about an integration that i found in *Weinberg-Gravitation (1972)*, specifically in 9.9 about Post-Newtonian approximation of Brans-Dicke theory. We need to solve at order $O(2)$ an equation of the form
$$ \nabla^2 g_{ij}^{(2)}(t, \vec{x}) = k \partial_i\partial_j\Phi(t, \vec{x}),$$
where $k$ is a costant for semplicity of notation. Now, using the Green function method, I found the general solution as
$$ g_{ij}^{(2)}(t, \vec{x}) = -\frac{k}{4\pi} \int d^3x' \frac{1}{|\vec{x} - \vec{x}'|}\partial'_i\partial'_j \Phi(t, \vec{x}')$$
Now, the function $\Phi$ in this case coincides with the Newtonian potential of a static spherically symmetric mass, thus, being a function of $r$ alone, Weinberg solves the integral in this way:
$$g_{ij}^{(2)}(t, \vec{x}) = k\left\{\left(\delta_{ij} - \frac{3x_ix_j}{r^2}\right)\frac1{r^3}\int_0^r r^2 \Phi(r)dr + \frac{x_ix_j}{r^2}\Phi \right\} $$
I think that he has used an integration by parts but despite my trials I could not find his result.
Could someone kindly explain to me in detail how to solve this integral? Furthermore, I would like to extend this case to the case of N point-mass bodies in which we have $\Phi \propto \sum_a \frac{m_a}{|\vec{x} - \vec{x}_a(t)|}$. Can this result still be extended to my particular case?

I thank everyone.